# Paul irish infinite scroll finished message not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

Have been using Paul Irish infinite scroll for the last few sites i've built but this new project has quite a lot of new callbacks for new elems.

The issue right now though is that the "No More Posts" finished message is not showing once is reaches the end of the sites internet and also the loading images is not being displayed during loading intervals.

Was wondering if anybody could spot something in the code I couldn't see. Would much appreciate it !

```
        //Infinite Scroll
        var $tilegrid = $('#content');
        var $initialNumberOfPosts = $('.post').length; // Get number of posts
        $tilegrid.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: ".load-more-btn",
            nextSelector: ".load-more-btn",
            itemSelector: ".post",
            behavior: 'twitter',
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: 'No more posts',
                img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/cmghtlm/zWPnh0xhe/ajax-loader.gif',
            }
        },
        function ( newElements ) {
            //call for likes
            var $currentNumberOfPosts = $('.post').length; 
            var pageNumber = Math.ceil($currentNumberOfPosts / $initialNumberOfPosts); 
            Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(pageNumber); 

            //images loaded isotope
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
              $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
              $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            });

            //photoset slider
            $('.photoset-slider').slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            });
        });
```